# Html : как прочитать текст файла после того как его выбрали через <input=file>

Tags: javascript, fileupload

Добрый день.

Ситуация: я на форме выбираю файл через стандартный `input=file`,  и мне нужно прочитать его текст.

(у меня нет ссылки на файл, соответственно, например через аякс прочитать его не могу)

Я использую **FileReader** ([link](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html)) и указываю там кодировку "`utf-8`".

Я этого желаю для того, чтобы преобразовать выбранный файл (PDF в данном случае) и отправить его строкой на сервер, а там уже back'овая часть из этой строки сделаем новый PDF, но у меня получается пустой (чистый PDF'ник, и я думаю, что файл считывается как-то неправильно).

**Вопрос:**

**Как еще можно прочитать содержимое выбранного файла, используя Javascript?**

Спасибо

Код:

```
//считываем файл после его выбора
function readSingleFile(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  //debugger;  

  $('.loader').toggle(true);
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  fileName = file.name;

  if (!file) {
    $('.loader').toggle(false);
    alert('Reading file failed:  ' + fileName);
    return;    
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e)  {

    //содержимое файла
    var fileContent = e.target.result;    

    //send to server    
    SendRequestToAction(fileContent);        
  };

  debugger;
  reader.readAsText(file, 'utf8');
```

Comment: Зачем так извращаться? Почему просто не отправить файл на сервер формой или FormData?

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать виртуальную форму, и прикрепить в нее ссылки на файлы.
Вот пример функции, где я отправлял несколько файлов за один клик. 
Без использования JQuery, поэтому прошу прощения, что не очень компактно.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="file[]" multiple="">
```

JS

```
function upload() {
    xmlHttp_upload = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xmlHttp_upload==null) { 
        return;
    } 

    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");
    if (file==null) { 
        return;
    } 
    var files = file.files;
    for (var i = 0;i<files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('file[]',file.files[i]); 
    }   

    var url="../core/route.php" 
    url=url+"?class=attach";
    url=url+"&method=upload";
//  xmlHttp_upload.onreadystatechange = process_response;
    xmlHttp_upload.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp_upload.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не нашел другого  варианта решения своего вопроса, поэтому я сделал вот как:
я взял тот же **FileReader** , но файл прочитал НЕ как текст, а как массив байт, и потом перевел в строку и все заработало.

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся!